# Find IMEI / ESN of attached device programmatically

Tags: c#, java, at-command, imei, jtapi

I need to get IMEI/ESN of a mobile device when it is connected with the computer system using USB.
What can I do? I came across JTAPI, but I am still not sure if there is an implementation good enough for my task.

PS: I of course need to do it programmaticaly. I am using Java, and targeting windows systems. So I am good with a C# solution too. :)

Best Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do it in a (semi) generic way, the only way is to send this on the (emulated) serial port of the phone;

```
AT+CGSN
```

Some/most phones allow it, some don't. Those that don't sometimes have a manufacturer specific way of getting the IMEI, some don't allow it at all.

In other words, if you need a solution that is 100% generic for every manufacturer, you're probably out of luck.